# Is it possible to create ListItem's attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In Material UI, ListItem is illustrated in http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list

The nested ListItem looks like so,

```
<ListItem
    value={1}
    primaryText="Brendan Lim"
    leftAvatar={<Avatar src="images/ok-128.jpg" />}
    nestedItems={[
      <ListItem
        value={2}
        primaryText="Grace Ng"
        leftAvatar={<Avatar src="images/uxceo-128.jpg" />}
      />,
    ]}
  />
```

My question is, is it possible to create a ListItem tag first and then insert nestedItems later?
I am looking for something like

```
let item=<ListItem... />; item.addAttribute(nestedList, list);
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Where are the `nestedItems` coming from? Is it an array being passed down as props? Something you're creating on-the-fly?

Comment: becausee the relationship of my UI  component is built as a tree, that means that the listedItem needs to be  created first, and pushed into a stack and when the program goes recursive to the leaves, then I can know the deepest nested list content, and it is only then that I can build and insert the nestedlist.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can conditionnally render your nestedItems :

```
<ListItem
    value={1}
    primaryText="Brendan Lim"
    leftAvatar={<Avatar src="images/ok-128.jpg" />}
    nestedItems={[
      {this.state.nestedItem && (<ListItem
        value={this.state.nestedItem.value}
        primaryText={this.state.nestedItem.text}
        leftAvatar={<Avatar src={this.state.nestedItem.avatarUrl} />}
      />)}
    ]}
  />
```

Comment: Thank you But my situation is that I create a ListItem without the nestedItems and its content because at first I don't know its content.

Comment: Yeah that's what i understood, `{this.state.nestedItem &&(<ListItem />)}` means `if this.state.nestedItem exists then display <ListItem />, if not do nothing`.